# ArcGIS JavaScript Print task not working in Internet Explorer 10. error: access is denied

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, internet-explorer

I have created a custom print task using my own custom templates and the Export Web Map tool in Server Tools of ArcGIS 10.2 to create a geoprocessing service similar to the print task made by Esri.

The geoprocessing service sits in the same directory as my map service for the mapping application I am working on.  In Internet Explorer 10, my map application works perfectly fine - but when I click on the Print button to print I get an error in the console stating "Access is denied".

I ended up adding a proxy to my application after getting the following error in the console when using the print button originally: "Error: esri.config.defaults.io.proxyUrl is not set.  IF making a request to a CORS enabled server, please push the domain into esri.confi.defaults.io.corsEnabledServers".

So I added a proxy into my application and then got the "Access is denied" error.  I tried the same functionality with Esri's out-of-the-box print task but had the same error.

Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?  My print button works in both Firefox and Chrome with no problems, and I thought by adding the proxy the problem would be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is definitely with your proxy.  current versions of both Chrome and Firefox support [CORS](http://caniuse.com/#search=cors), but IE10 does not, so the browser needs to fall back on a working proxy in order to POST across domains.

my best guess is that the 'access is denied' message is coming directly from your own proxy.  try accessing the print service directly in the browser in order to make sure its configured appropriately.

for example:
http://yourmachine/yourproxy.ashx?http://utility.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer?f=json

if the proxy responds with anything different than the print service does when called directly.  something is amiss.

Comment: I ended up getting it to work in my test environment using IIS 7.  I ended up needing to change the ASP.NET version from 2.0 to 4.0 and then got it working.  Thanks for your help though!